# List MP3 files and durations

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3

So I want to show a list of MP3 files with their durations.

`ffprobe` does show me the duration of a file. But its output is nasty. It puts everything into `stderr` and I have found no way to remove its "very helpful" information about how it was compiled.

So if I loop it through `*.mp3`, that information is displayed every single time.

I could write a filter script but might there be a simpler solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the total duration of all video files in current folder and sub-directories](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/587646/how-to-get-the-total-duration-of-all-video-files-in-current-folder-and-sub-direc)

Answer (score 4):

To get an output like this:

```
00:07:22 first.mp3
00:02:33 second.mp3
00:04:04 third.mp3
```

use:

```bash
for file in *.mp3
do
  echo -n $(ffprobe "$file" 2>&1 | grep 'Duration' | cut -d',' -f1 | cut -d' ' -f4 | cut -d'.' -f1)
  echo " $file"
done
```

where

- `2>&1` redirects stderr to stdout
- `grep ...` filters just the line with the duration
- 1st `cut ...` extracts `Duration: 00:07:22.33`
- 2nd `cut ...` extracts `00:07:22.33`
- 3rd `cut ...` extracts `00:07:22`

Answer (score 2):

You can easily get rid of the information that is put into `stderr` with the `-loglevel -quiet` option. In that case you have to have to query the field you want to display.

```
[user@host ~]$ ffprobe -loglevel quiet -show_entries format=duration test/test.mp3 
[FORMAT]
duration=172.434286
[/FORMAT]
```

---

Now this does still gives some extra information which can be stripped down and the duration in seconds.

```
[user@host test]$ ffprobe -loglevel quiet -show_entries format=duration \-print_format default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -pretty test.mp3 
0:02:52.434286
```

Here, the `-print_format` can be used to get rid of the extra information:

- `default=noprint_wrappers=1` will remove the `[FORMAT]` stuff
- `nokey=1` will remove the keyname `duration=`

Last but not least, you can use `-pretty` or just `-sexagesimal` to convert the duration in seconds to a `HH:MM:SS.MICROSECONDS` format.

---

To find all MP3 files in a folder you could combine `find` and the `ffprobe` command from above.

```
[user@host ~]$ find test/ -name '*mp3' -printf "%f:\t" -exec ffprobe -loglevel error -print_format default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -pretty -show_entries stream=duration "{}" \;
test.mp3:   0:02:52.434286
```