# How to get the total duration of all video files in current folder and sub-directories

Tags: ls, xargs, ffmpeg

I am trying to get the duration of a bunch of files in current directory and its sub-directories all ending in .mp4. I'm trying to use ffprobe. To make things simple, I am not using find, but ls. If it only lists durations in seconds, it will be fine, since summing them all up would probably be beyond me!

My current effort is like this:

```
 ls -a * |grep .mp4$|xargs ffprobe
```

This shows

> Argument 'SomeVideo.mp4' provided as input filename, but 'DifferentVideo.mp4' was already specified.

How can I make this work? Can ffprobe not just process one file at a time passed via pipe?

Comment: Seems like xargs passes all the lines of video file names. Oh, one more thing. This does not show file paths. So, ffprobe will not find the files. WTH

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With `exiftool`:

```
$ exiftool -ext mp4 -r -n -q -p '${Duration;$_ = ConvertDuration(our $total += $_)}' . | tail -n 1
4 days 22:14:59
```

The main difference from [@don_cristi's answer to a very similar question](/a/170973), being the `-r -ext mp4` which lets exiftool look for files with `ext`ensions `r`ecursively.

Answer (score 2):

To address your underlying requirement, you should iterate across the files, passing them one at a time to `ffprobe`. This will allow you to get the durations in hours, minutes, seconds.

```
for mp4 in *.mp4
do
    echo "Processing $mp4"
    ffprobe "$mp4" 2>&1 | awk '/Duration/ {print $2}'
done
```

Looking around somewhat [more carefully](https://superuser.com/a/945604), it's possible to get `ffprobe` to deliver seconds directly

```
for mp4 in *.mp4
do
    echo "Processing $mp4"
    ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$mp4"
done
```

Having done that, it's not a giant leap to add them all together

```
for mp4 in *.mp4
do
    echo "Processing $mp4"
    ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$mp4"
done |
    awk -F '
        { sec += $1 }                                                # Total time (seconds)
        END {
            h = int(sec / 3600);                                     # Hours
            m = int((sec - (h*3600)) / 60);                          # Minutes
            s = sec - (h*3600) - (m*60);                             # Seconds
            printf "%d (%d hour, %d min, %d sec)\n", sec, h, m, s    # Print the result
        }
    '
```

Finally, to process files not only in the current directory but also in all subdirectories, modify the outer loop. This next step uses a `bash` feature that allows `**` to match subdirectories

```
shopt -s globstar                                                    # Enable extended globbing
for mp4 in **/*.mp4
do
    echo "Processing $mp4"
    ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$mp4"
done |
    # Continue as before...
```

Answer (score 1):

`xargs` will add as many arguments from the input as possible in the command - it does not know of the one-file limit of `ffprobe`

If you want to run `ffprobe` once per input, use

```
 ... | xargs -l ffprobe
```

or

```
 ... |  xargs -L 1 ffprobe
```

For understanding, just compare the output of these two commands

```
  seq 1 3 | xargs echo
  seq 1 3 | xargs -l echo
```

Please note that using `ls`-output as input is discouraged for several reasons.

Better use `find` - despite your effort for simplification - best by using a `NULL`-separator to avoid problems with special characters:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -name '*mp4' -print0 | xargs -0 ffprobe
```

Next problem is the output of `ffprobe` - get seconds only like done [here](https://superuser.com/a/945604/471276). Then you might just sum it up using e.g. `awk`.